# Increase the analog sample rate of the IOIO?

Tags: analog, android, input, sparkfun

On the [analogue input wiki page](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/Analog-Input) for the [Sparkfun IOIO](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11343) (android development board), it says that the analogue pins are sampled at 1kHz. This is too low for a number of potentially exciting uses, like multiple-channel audio input, or use as an oscilloscope, or logic probe. But the wiki page says that the physical limitation is 500kHz, which would be more than enough for some of those uses. Is it possible to modify the current generation of IOIOs to increase the analogue sample rate?

Comment: A schematic of the circuit you're asking about would help you get answers from people who don't know the designs of every Sparkfun board off the tops of their heads.

Comment: Taking a quick look, it seems the IOIO is based on a PIC24F chip, so changing the sample rate probably involves reprogramming the chip and the corrsponding Java library on the host. There's a [Google Group specifically for IOIO support](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/ioio-users); you'll probably get a better answer if you ask there. This sort of question is too localized for SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Google ioio users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ioio-users/QsaHtn-9pRE) 2011 this extract:

... the line saying

```
PR3   = 0x07CF;
```

In the file `firmware/app_layer_v1/adc.c` should be changed to

```
PR3 = <whatever sampling period you want>,
```

where the units are in 0.5 micoseconds.

Another small change you may want to do: the `AnalogInutImpl.setValue()` method gets called every time a fresh sample arrives from the IOIO. You may want to push them into a queue so that none gets lost instead of just storing the most recent value, as in the current implementation.

appears to be what's wanted.

There is extensive discussion involving this at the above address.

And [similar here from August 2012](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ioio-users/MN2RopVVx-s)

And [probably this too - 2011 again](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/ioio-users/MN2RopVVx-s/5569Vhw7ux0J)